# Solr Query Delete Limit To 3 Records?

Tags: json, solr

Been using Solr 3.2 and the query delete function limits to 3 records so far. If I send in more than 3, will get the following error:

> Apache Tomcat/7.0.12 - Error
>   report525D76;}-->
>
> ## HTTP Status 500 - JSON Parse Error: char=,,position=77
>
> BEFORE='":"listingid:623787"},"delete":{"query":"listingid:656349"}},'
>   AFTER='{"delete":{"query":"listingid:955907"}}'
>
> org.apache.noggit.JSONParser$ParseException: JSON Parse Error:
>   char=,,position=77
>   BEFORE='":"listingid:623787"},"delete":{"query":"listingid:656349"}},'
>   AFTER='{"delete":{"query":"listingid:955907"}}'
>     at org.apache.noggit.JSONParser.err(JSONParser.java:223)    at
>   org.apache.noggit.JSONParser.next(JSONParser.java:622)    at
>   org.apache.noggit.JSONParser.nextEvent(JSONParser.java:663)   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.JsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:148)
>     at org.apache.solr.handler.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:74)  at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:241)
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1360)    at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message**
>   JSON Parse Error: char=,,position=77
>   BEFORE='":"listingid:623787"},"delete":{"query":"listingid:656349"}},'
>   AFTER='{"delete":{"query":"listingid:955907"}}'
>
> org.apache.noggit.JSONParser$ParseException: JSON Parse Error:
>   char=,,position=77
>   BEFORE='":"listingid:623787"},"delete":{"query":"listingid:656349"}},'
>   AFTER='{"delete":{"query":"listingid:955907"}}'
>     at org.apache.noggit.JSONParser.err(JSONParser.java:223)    at
>   org.apache.noggit.JSONParser.next(JSONParser.java:622)    at
>   org.apache.noggit.JSONParser.nextEvent(JSONParser.java:663)   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.JsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:148)
>     at org.apache.solr.handler.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:74)  at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:241)
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1360)    at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> **description** The server encountered an internal
>   error (JSON Parse Error: char=,,position=77
>   BEFORE='":"listingid:623787"},"delete":{"query":"listingid:656349"}},'
>   AFTER='{"delete":{"query":"listingid:955907"}}'
>
> org.apache.noggit.JSONParser$ParseException: JSON Parse Error:
>   char=,,position=77
>   BEFORE='":"listingid:623787"},"delete":{"query":"listingid:656349"}},'
>   AFTER='{"delete":{"query":"listingid:955907"}}'
>     at org.apache.noggit.JSONParser.err(JSONParser.java:223)    at
>   org.apache.noggit.JSONParser.next(JSONParser.java:622)    at
>   org.apache.noggit.JSONParser.nextEvent(JSONParser.java:663)   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.JsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:148)
>     at org.apache.solr.handler.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:74)  at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:241)
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1360)    at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) ) that prevented it from
>   fulfilling this request.
>
> #### Apache Tomcat/7.0.12

I had checked the JSON format using JSONLint and its working fine.  Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: This is the current format being tested and I uses curl to perform unit test also confirm this.

> [{"listingid"  : "793814"},{"listingid"  : "812905"},{"listingid"  :
>   "1028111"},{"listingid"  : "454482"},{"listingid"  : "1011465"}]

Comment: can you post the json you are using ?

Comment: Most likely you have a dangling trailing comma: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i had figure this out, look at the original query:

{"delete":{"query":"listingid:1185"},"delete":{"query":"listingid:1184"}},{"delete":{"query":"listingid:1183"}},{"delete":{"query":"listingid:1172"}}

do notice that the encapsulation is wrong, it should be:

{"delete":{"query":"listingid:1185"},"delete":{"query":"listingid:1184"},"delete":{"query":"listingid:1183"},"delete":{"query":"listingid:1172"}}

thanks for the help from all of you