# Default Controls - How can I disable controlNav and directionNav?

Tags: wordpress, flexslider

I am trying to disable the controlNav and directionNav controls within flexslider.  I am using the risen theme from themeforest and the theme is using jquery.flexslider-min.js.  If I use the full jquery.flexslider.js there is the following options that I can disable controlNav or directionNav.

How can I either disable this from my functions.php or the jquery.flexsliders-min.js?

```
$.flexslider.defaults = {
namespace: "flex-",             //{NEW} String: Prefix string attached to the class of every element generated by the plugin
selector: ".slides > li",       //{NEW} Selector: Must match a simple pattern. '{container} > {slide}' -- Ignore pattern at your own peril
animation: "fade",              //String: Select your animation type, "fade" or "slide"
easing: "swing",               //{NEW} String: Determines the easing method used in jQuery transitions. jQuery easing plugin is supported!
direction: "horizontal",        //String: Select the sliding direction, "horizontal" or "vertical"
reverse: false,                 //{NEW} Boolean: Reverse the animation direction
animationLoop: true,             //Boolean: Should the animation loop? If false, directionNav will received "disable" classes at either end
smoothHeight: false,            //{NEW} Boolean: Allow height of the slider to animate smoothly in horizontal mode  
startAt: 0,                     //Integer: The slide that the slider should start on. Array notation (0 = first slide)
slideshow: true,                //Boolean: Animate slider automatically
slideshowSpeed: 7000,           //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
animationSpeed: 600,            //Integer: Set the speed of animations, in milliseconds
initDelay: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Set an initialization delay, in milliseconds
randomize: false,               //Boolean: Randomize slide order

// Usability features
pauseOnAction: true,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when interacting with control elements, highly recommended.
pauseOnHover: false,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when hovering over slider, then resume when no longer hovering
useCSS: true,                   //{NEW} Boolean: Slider will use CSS3 transitions if available
touch: true,                    //{NEW} Boolean: Allow touch swipe navigation of the slider on touch-enabled devices
video: false,                   //{NEW} Boolean: If using video in the slider, will prevent CSS3 3D Transforms to avoid graphical glitches

// Primary Controls
controlNav: true,               //Boolean: Create navigation for paging control of each clide? Note: Leave true for manualControls usage
directionNav: true,             //Boolean: Create navigation for previous/next navigation? (true/false)
prevText: "Previous",           //String: Set the text for the "previous" directionNav item
nextText: "Next",               //String: Set the text for the "next" directionNav item

// Secondary Navigation
keyboard: true,                 //Boolean: Allow slider navigating via keyboard left/right keys
multipleKeyboard: false,        //{NEW} Boolean: Allow keyboard navigation to affect multiple sliders. Default behavior cuts out keyboard navigation with more than one slider present.
mousewheel: false,              //{UPDATED} Boolean: Requires jquery.mousewheel.js (https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) - Allows slider navigating via mousewheel
pausePlay: false,               //Boolean: Create pause/play dynamic element
pauseText: "Pause",             //String: Set the text for the "pause" pausePlay item
playText: "Play",               //String: Set the text for the "play" pausePlay item

// Special properties
controlsContainer: "",          //{UPDATED} jQuery Object/Selector: Declare which container the navigation elements should be appended too. Default container is the FlexSlider element. Example use would be $(".flexslider-container"). Property is ignored if given element is not found.
manualControls: "",             //{UPDATED} jQuery Object/Selector: Declare custom control navigation. Examples would be $(".flex-control-nav li") or "#tabs-nav li img", etc. The number of elements in your controlNav should match the number of slides/tabs.
sync: "",                       //{NEW} Selector: Mirror the actions performed on this slider with another slider. Use with care.
asNavFor: "",                   //{NEW} Selector: Internal property exposed for turning the slider into a thumbnail navigation for another slider

// Carousel Options
itemWidth: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Box-model width of individual carousel items, including horizontal borders and padding.
itemMargin: 0,                  //{NEW} Integer: Margin between carousel items.
minItems: 0,                    //{NEW} Integer: Minimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when below this.
maxItems: 0,                    //{NEW} Integer: Maxmimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when above this limit.
move: 0,                        //{NEW} Integer: Number of carousel items that should move on animation. If 0, slider will move all visible items.

// Callback API
start: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider loads the first slide
before: function(){},           //Callback: function(slider) - Fires asynchronously with each slider animation
after: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires after each slider animation completes
end: function(){},              //Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider reaches the last slide (asynchronous)
added: function(){},            //{NEW} Callback: function(slider) - Fires after a slide is added
removed: function(){}           //{NEW} Callback: function(slider) - Fires after a slide is removed
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change to

```
controlNav: false,

directionNav: false,
```

Comment: Hi Kee.  The issue is that the jquery.flexslider-min.js file does not contain this code and there is no way to set the variable to false.  As a workaround, I copied the full js into the jquery.flexslider-min.js file and set these to false. I am trying to come up with a way from within the jquery.flexslider-min.js file to do the same or from my functions.php.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#.slider').flexslider({            
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: false
});
```

see the documentation [here](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties).

Answer (score 1):

As Kee said, but this is how to do it when you load the slider instead of editing the source JS file:

```
$('#.flexslider').flexslider({            
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: false
});
```

Comment: FYI JSON spec does not allow trailing commas such as in your example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object

Comment: how I can do only disable nav when only 1 item?