# PHP + Javascript error: Unexpected token D

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have an error:

> Unexpected token D

When I try to send JSON from JavaScript to PHP. I know that error is caused on server side and I tried to fix it, but then I get another errors like `Unexpected input`, `Unexpected end` and similar.

I am trying to fix it during 1 week and have no result. My goal is to send data to server and make server show it without errors, how can I do it?

My client code:

```
$("#sendRoute").live('click', function () {
    trackCoords_str = JSON.stringify(trackCoords);
    final_time_m_str = JSON.stringify(final_time_m);
    final_time_s_rounded_str = JSON.stringify(final_time_s_rounded);
    aver_speed_km_h_rounded_str = JSON.stringify(aver_speed_km_h_rounded);
    total_km_rounded_str = JSON.stringify(total_km_rounded);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://test.whirlware.biz/server/index.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            route: trackCoords_str,
            timeInMinutes: final_time_m_str,
            timeInSeconds: final_time_s_rounded_str,
            averageSpeed: aver_speed_km_h_rounded_str,
            distance: total_km_rounded_str,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (){alert("success!");},
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

My server code:

```
 $route = $_POST['route'];
 $timeInMinutes = $_POST['timeInMinutes'];
 $timeInSeconds = $_POST['timeInSeconds'];
 $averageSpeed = $_POST['averageSpeed'];
 $distance = $_POST['distance'];

 $trackCoords1 = json_encode($route);
 $final_time_m1 = json_encode($timeInMinutes);
 $final_time_s_rounded1 = json_encode($timeInSeconds);
 $aver_speed_km_h_rounded1 = json_encode($averageSpeed);
 $total_km_rounded1 = json_encode($distance);

 echo "Distance: </br>"; echo $distance;
 echo "Time in minutes: </br>"; echo $timeInMinutes;
 echo "Time in seconds: </br>"; echo $timeInSeconds;
 echo "Average speed: </br>"; echo $averageSpeed;
```

Comment: In the jQuery you say you want to retrieve JSON from the server. You are not sending back JSON from the server. As far as I can tell, that's the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client expects to get JSON, so you need to send back valid JSON … and *only* valid JSON.

What this means is that you should really only call `json_encode` a single time.  Your code should probably be more like:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    "distance" => $distance,
    "time in minutes" => $timeInMinutes
    //etc.
));
```

Either that, or just use HTML instead of JSON and remove the `dataType: json` line on the client.

Comment: It works like in your example but on the server all variables return null, why?

Comment: I alos tried to change datatype to html but error was the same

Answer (score 3):

Your error is:

> Unexpected token D

Then going to [your site’s URL,](http://test.whirlware.biz/server/index.php) the output is simply:

```
Distance: </br>Time in minutes: </br>Time in seconds: </br>Average speed: </br>
```

The “unexpected token” which is `D` is referring to the first letter of your output which is the word *Distance*.

It is unclear to me what the goal of the PHP code is. Do you expect that when it connects to that PHP code it takes the data and adds it to the database?

Meaning your path is currently now:

> JavaScript Ajax via $_POST -> PHP parsing of $_POST -> And that PHP
>   script is echoing contents?

What do those `echo`s have to do with the process? What happens when you just comment out the `echo`s?

Let’s look at your code:

```
$route = $_POST['route'];
$timeInMinutes = $_POST['timeInMinutes'];
$timeInSeconds = $_POST['timeInSeconds'];
$averageSpeed = $_POST['averageSpeed'];
$distance = $_POST['distance'];

$trackCoords1 = json_encode($route);
$final_time_m1 = json_encode($timeInMinutes);
$final_time_s_rounded1 = json_encode($timeInSeconds);
$aver_speed_km_h_rounded1 = json_encode($averageSpeed);
$total_km_rounded1 = json_encode($distance);

echo "Distance: </br>"; echo $distance;
echo "Time in minutes: </br>"; echo $timeInMinutes;
echo "Time in seconds: </br>"; echo $timeInSeconds;
echo "Average speed: </br>"; echo $averageSpeed;
```

What exactly is this about?  So in the first ones you are assigning variables:

```
$route = $_POST['route'];
$timeInMinutes = $_POST['timeInMinutes'];
$timeInSeconds = $_POST['timeInSeconds'];
$averageSpeed = $_POST['averageSpeed'];
$distance = $_POST['distance'];
```

Okay, and then in the next one you are using `json_encode` on those variables:

```
$trackCoords1 = json_encode($route);
$final_time_m1 = json_encode($timeInMinutes);
$final_time_s_rounded1 = json_encode($timeInSeconds);
$aver_speed_km_h_rounded1 = json_encode($averageSpeed);
$total_km_rounded1 = json_encode($distance);
```

Then what are these?

```
echo "Distance: </br>"; echo $distance;
echo "Time in minutes: </br>"; echo $timeInMinutes;
echo "Time in seconds: </br>"; echo $timeInSeconds;
echo "Average speed: </br>"; echo $averageSpeed;
```

And what are you now doing with those `json_encode` variables?  What is the goal of your script. It’s simply a mess.

Perhaps your code in the PHP file that is your server code should simply be this:

```
$json_output = array();
$json_output['route'] = $_POST['route'];
$json_output['timeInMinutes'] = $_POST['timeInMinutes'];
$json_output['timeInSeconds'] = $_POST['timeInSeconds'];
$json_output['averageSpeed'] = $_POST['averageSpeed'];
$json_output['distance'] = $_POST['distance'];

echo json_encode($json_output);
```

**EDIT** Also, looking at your JavaScript code, you have a trailing comma in your JSON. And [as explained on this question & answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object) that is not allowed in the JSON spec. So I would change this:

```
data: {
    route: trackCoords_str,
    timeInMinutes: final_time_m_str,
    timeInSeconds: final_time_s_rounded_str,
    averageSpeed: aver_speed_km_h_rounded_str,
    distance: total_km_rounded_str,
},
```

To be this; note the comma after `total_km_rounded_str,` is removed to make it simply `total_km_rounded_str`:

```
data: {
    route: trackCoords_str,
    timeInMinutes: final_time_m_str,
    timeInSeconds: final_time_s_rounded_str,
    averageSpeed: aver_speed_km_h_rounded_str,
    distance: total_km_rounded_str
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I know it, how can  get rid of this error?

Comment: Your solution works, but it returns "null" in all variables, how can I solve it?

Comment: Yes, they have values, when I had errors previously, variables were in this errors, they exist 100%. If you have no idea how to solve it please tell how to send data in html?

Comment: I removed it but result is same :(

Comment: If you want I can provide all source code, but I it`s too huge for StckOverflow.

Comment: Here is my full js code http://jsfiddle.net/9nxwg/ and link to my app http://test.whirlware.biz/client/ if it makes sense. Hope for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Delete the comma here

```
distance: total_km_rounded_str
                              ^ HERE
```