# Array values not inserting into database separately

Tags: php, arrays, insert

I'm not sure exactly how to phrase this so I will show an example.  I'm gathering input values in javascript and passing to my php page where I am trying to insert those values in a database.

Instead of inserting separate values it is inserting the entire string.

Part of my javascript below:

```
var form = document.forms[0];
var txtS = form["bulletlabels"];
var len = txtS.length;
var bulletlabels = "";
for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
    bulletlabels += '"'+[i]+'_'+(txtS[i].value)+'_label",';
    }
```

when I do an alert(bulletlabels); I get this:

`"0_Lot Size_label","1_Rooms_label","2_Bathrooms_label","3_Basement_label",`

On my php page I have:

```
$bulletlabels = array($_POST['bulletlabels']);

$length = count($bulletlabels);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE bullets SET bullettitle = '".$bulletlabels[$i]."' WHERE bulletrow = ($i+1)");
}
```

This inserts the below string into the database on ONE Row which is not the desired effect:

`"0_Lot Size_label","1_Rooms_label","2_Bathrooms_label","3_Basement_label",`

But here is the key to my confusion - if I **manually type the string in, it inserts onto individual database rows as desired.**

This inserts values individually as desired when typed manually:

`$bulletlabels = array("0_Lot Size_label","1_Rooms_label","2_Bathrooms_label","3_Basement_label",);`

Does NOT work and inserts the full concatenated string:
`$bulletlabels = array($_POST['bulletlabels']);`

Hope I explained well enough - arrays elude me.

EDIT:
Fix for the trailing comma:

```
var delim = "";
for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
bulletlabels += delim+[i]+'_'+(txtS[i].value)+'_label';
delim = ",";
}
```

Reference link for trailing comma fix:

[Can you use a trailing comma in a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object)

Comment: `var_dump($bulletlabels);` and you'll see that it isn't what you believed. What you can do is use proper JSON syntax and then `json_decode()` the posted string resulting in an array

Comment: After you get the values from the `$_POST` array, use `print_r` or `var_dump` to see what you have. I think you'll find it's an array of strings with only one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the following line:

```
$bulletlabels = array($_POST['bulletlabels']);
```

to

```
$bulletlabels = explode(',', $_POST['bulletlabels']);
```

Also do not add quotes in your javascript:

```
 bulletlabels += '"'+[i]+'_'+(txtS[i].value)+'_label",';
```

should be

```
 bulletlabels += [i]+'_'+(txtS[i].value)+'_label,';
```

**Explanation:**

Currently, $bulletlabels is an array with one element, and this element is the following string: `"0_Lot Size_label","1_Rooms_label","2_Bathrooms_label","3_Basement_label",`. However, you want to have an array with several strings. That's why you need to use [the explode function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to convert it into a proper array.

**Note:**

Make sure not to include `,` in the label names, as it will break with this implementation. If you need to be able to use `,` too, you should use json functions.

Comment: Sure, that won't work. Added a hint to the answer to use json in that case.

Comment: Although I believe you should use JSON anyhow instead of a workaround, you can't change OP's mind - so good answer and +1 ;)

Comment: I tried your solution and took into consideration your advice on commas causing issues.  Please see my edit - I found a solution for the trailing comma here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object  But I am hoping that is acceptable coding practice as I'm uneducated of the json function you are referring to.  I will mark yours as the answer and I appreciate the explanation!