# AngularJS load data from multiple json files

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to load data from multiple files, and I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong.
This is my controller.js:

```
angular.module('QuizQuestions.controllers', [])
  .controller('Preguntas', function($scope,$http) {
    $http.get('data/preguntas.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.preguntas = data;
    });
    $http.get('data/tags.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.tags = data;
    });
  });
```

preguntas.json:

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "text": "Is this okay?",
 }
]
```

tags.json:

```
[
    { text: 'just' },
    { text: 'some' },
    { text: 'cool' },
    { text: 'tags' }
]
```

When I try to access the preguntas.json it's empty, it only loads the tags.json, but checking the network responses, I can see that it loads firs tags.json, then preguntas.json, but only loads the data from the first one.

Where I'm wrong here?

Comment: Please post a sample of the data from both `tags.json` and `preguntas.json`.

Comment: Code is good... must be other problem

Comment: throw a console.log(data) in each one..see if the data is coming in

Comment: I've added the jsons, I think they are ok.
I've noticed that the second, preguntas.json, gives a 304 response, not a 200.

Comment: You have a trailing comma after `"text": "Is this okay?"`, which may cause an error when parsing the JSON. (source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object)

Comment: Thank you! That solved it, i hadn't noticed.