# Why do I get the error "unexpected end of string while parsing JSON string" when decoding a URI-encoded JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json, perl, post

I'm trying to POST some JSON data to my Perl script, but the JSON module seems to be unable to cope with this string:

```
[{"":"#","jednostka":"","login":"SA"}]
```

I used `encodeURIComponent()` in JavaScript, so my string actually looks like this:

```
[{%22%22:%22#%22,%22jednostka%22:%22%22,%22login%22:%22SA%22}]
```

Error log:

```
JSON::PP::decode_error('unexpected end of string while parsing JSON string') called at C:\strawberry\perl\lib/JSON/PP.pm line 837
|   JSON::PP::string() called at C:\strawberry\perl\lib/JSON/PP.pm line 960
|   JSON::PP::object() called at C:\strawberry\perl\lib/JSON/PP.pm line 724
|   JSON::PP::value() called at C:\strawberry\perl\lib/JSON/PP.pm line 907
|   JSON::PP::array() called at C:\strawberry\perl\lib/JSON/PP.pm line 725
|   JSON::PP::value() called at C:\strawberry\perl\lib/JSON/PP.pm line 688
|   JSON::PP::PP_decode_json('JSON::PP=HASH(0xd0c2534)', '[{%22%22:%22#%22,%22jednostka%22:%22%22,%22login%22:%22SA%22}]', 0) called at C:\strawberry\perl\lib/JSON/PP.pm line 148
```

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON? Have you tried `JSON.parse('[{"":"#","jednostka":"","login":"SA"}]')` ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the encodeURIComponent(). doesn't it work without it? and shouldn't you do decode on the other side?

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](https://www.evernote.com/l/AAP7BEqr1thL6K50DGUQnnj7OviXVfoo_fk), you need to provide an [MCVE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you realise that you ned to escape the data only for GET requests? That's why the function is called `encodeURIComponent`, because the resulting string is for use within a URL. In POST requests the data is passed in the message body, not in the URL

I see that you're using the [`JSON::PP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP) module, which works fine with the simple JSON string that you show. Here's an example program that shows the resulting data structure dumped using `Data::Dump`

Acccording to the error log you're encoding the JSON data when you shouldn't be. If I replace the JSON data below with `encodeURIComponent` then I get the error message

> unexpected end of string while parsing JSON string, at character offset 3 (before "22%22:%22#%22,%22jed...")

which is as you described, and what the error log confirms

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use JSON::PP;
use Data::Dump;

my $json = '[{"":"#","jednostka":"","login":"SA"}]';

my $data = JSON::PP::decode_json($json);

dd $data;
```

#### output

```
[{ "" => "#", "jednostka" => "", "login" => "SA" }]
```

Comment: Someone fuction after Encoding change " to %22 that was problem. I need to change value="VALUE " to value='Value'. End no change " to %22 in html.

Comment: Other option is replace " to &qout;

Comment: My error was in the text element: I had a return inside the string and after removing the invisible return, the `unexpected end of string` went.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the "*unexpected end of string while parsing JSON string*" from Perl's JSON::decode_json() function, is if your JSON file contains [trailing commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object), like this:

```
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500,
    }  }}
```

The [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) does not allow a trailing comma (this is unrelated to URI-encoding, btw). You should be able to catch such JSON format violations using JSON::Parse::[valid_json()](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/JSON-Parse/lib/JSON/Parse.pod#valid_json).

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're decoding it in Perl, but attempting to decode an empty variable name.  Give the first variable a name.