# Vanilla ES6 aJax call Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, ajax

Trying to return some JSON code from the server so I can manipulate it within the JavaScript.

However i'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 10

Here is my code:

```
getJSON(url, success) {
      let query = [ 'cars', 'vans', 'bikes' ];

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            success(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
          } else {
            exit(xhr.responseText);
          }
        }
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
    }
```

This is the response I get if I just console.log the `xhr.responseText`:

```
[
  {
    make: 'VOLVO'
  },
  {
    make: 'AUDI'
  },
  {
    make: 'VOLKSWAGON'
  },
]
```

Comment: This is not valid JSON. JSON can't have trailing commas and always requires double quotes for property names and strings.

Comment: Crap, my mistake. I messed up the JSON

Comment: You may want to catch the error in order to fail gracefully when server returns invalid data.

Comment: You need to wrap your strings in quotes. Your _"make"_ key is missing the opening quote, that is what the console is telling you. It is expecting a `"`, but it found an `m`. Voted to close, because this is a data issue, not a coding issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you are trying to parse is a valid JavaScript object, but not a valid JSON.

`key`s should be strings, which are defined as

> a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes

You should not use any trailing comma (see [Can you use a trailing comma in a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object)).

A proper JSON string for your object should be:

```
let s = '[ {"make": "VOLVO"}, {"make": "AUDI"}, {"make": "VOLKSWAGON"} ]';
```

Code could be fixed to detect this problem:

```
getJSON(url, success) {
    let query = [ 'cars', 'vans', 'bikes' ];
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                try {
                    let parsedJSON = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    success(parsedJSON);
                } catch (e) {
                    if (e instanceof SyntaxError === true) {
                        // Problem with the format of the JSON string.
                    } else {
                        // Other error
                    }
                }
            } else {
                exit(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
}
```

---

Misc. resources:

- [The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt)
- [Introducing JSON](http://www.json.org/)