# What does this error info. from node/express mean?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, node-config

I have this simple local.JSON file I use with node-config:

```
{

  "MySQL": {
    "connection": "mysql://root:foo@localhost/heroku_d093ad5a46d841c?reconnect=true",
  },

  "Mongoose": {
    "connection": "mongodb://localhost/myapp"
  }

}
```

However, I get this error from nodemon:

> Error: Cannot parse config file:
>   '/Users/foo/root/repo_fave/config/local.json': SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token } in JSON at position 110

Particularly what does the 110 refer to.  Is it the 110th character if the file was treated as a single line of string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use a trailing comma in a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object)

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your JSON. In the `MySQL` block you have:

```
"MySQL": {
  "connection": "mysql://root:foo@localhost/heroku_d093ad5a46d841c?reconnect=true",
},
```

This should be:

```
"MySQL": {
  "connection": "mysql://root:foo@localhost/heroku_d093ad5a46d841c?reconnect=true"
},
```

Please note the removed comma at the end of the inner line. And yes, the `110` refers to the 110th character.

PS: To figure out what problems like these are, you might be interested in [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/), a website to validate (and find errors in) JSON.

Comment: Of course, your comment was *not* a waste of time 

Comment: Also for sure! `:)`

Comment: Then why are you starting such a crappy discussion instead of either shutting up or helping a beginner?

Comment: Because typo answers are waste of time for everyone in this community my bro and you know that!

Comment: Have a good day! `:)`