# Parse Google Map String To an JS array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I had developed a google map function in which on call a google map is drawn according to the data is passed

Example:

```
function DrawMap(data){
   //code to draw google map
}
```

data was passed in following format

```
['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
```

But data was came from php 
so by default i am sending data like

```
var defaultLocation = [
    <?php
        foreach ($db_data as $mvalue) {
            echo "[ '".$mvalue['vTripStatus']."',".$mvalue['vLatitude'].",".$mvalue['vLongitude']." ],";
        } 
    ?>
];
```

But i have made an event on click of button which performs an ajax call so in ajax the data was returned as string in following format (when i console.log())

```
[[ 'Active',23.0123022,72.5033961 ],[ 'Arrived',23.0088,72.4823 ],[ 'On Going Trip',22.9938,72.4713 ], ]
```

so this format isnt accepted by google map so it do not load the map.

**i tried $.parseJSON and JSON.parse() too**
So how i can convert it like

[image]

Comment: to convert the object array and send response to ajax.

Comment: while printing in array `comma` after last element is causing that problem, it is not needed.

Comment: yes also single quote is causing problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i read this [Can you use a trailing comma in a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object)

The problem is single quote and an extra comma which is in

```
[
  [ 'Active',23.0123022,72.5033961 ],
  [ 'Arrived',23.0088,72.4823 ],
  [ 'On Going Trip',22.9938,72.4713 ],
]
```

It cause problem while parsing the json data.
so if you use an string in json data you must have to compulsary use Double quote(") instead single quote(")

and as well extra words and symbol's are also not allowed in json data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the values PHP is outputting are strings. Try:

```
var defaultLocation = JSON.parse(`
    <?php
        $arr = [];
        foreach ($db_data as $mvalue) {
            $arr[] = [ $mvalue['vTripStatus'], $mvalue['vLatitude'], $mvalue['vLongitude'] ];
        }
        echo json_encode($arr);
    ?>
`);
```

Comment: Looks like I forgot to put the php code within a string. The code should work now