# NameValueCollection into equivalent javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, namevaluecollection

I have a c# code that uses NameValueCollection, and then webclient to send a post request to API.

I need to use an equivalent request but using javascript instead of c#, I tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "message": "xyz",
                "token": "xyz",
                "user": "xyz",
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("push sent!");
            }
        });
```

But I get a 400 error, stating "bad request".

Please ignore the security perspective as the token & user are available to the user.

c# code is:

```
var parameters = new NameValueCollection {
            { "token", "xyz" },
            { "user", "xyz" },
            { "message", "xyz" }
        };

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.UploadValues("https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json", parameters);
    }
```

Comment: You say you tried something but it didn't work. What did you try?

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: `FormData` + `fetch()`

Comment: Hi @MattEllen, I tried something like below: 
`$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "message": "xyz",
                "token": "xyz",
                "user": "xyz",
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("push sent!");
            }
        });`

Comment: Hi @Andreas, would you explain more please?

Comment: Did you get some kind of error? What behaviour did you expect?

Comment: Yes @MattEllen, I got error "400 bad requests" when I tried to use the javascript code, on the other hand, c# code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my machine right now so I can't test this, but I would guess that you're not setting the content type in the `Header` property of the webclient in c#, so that is [defaulting to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadvalues?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_WebClient_UploadValues_System_String_System_Collections_Specialized_NameValueCollection_) but in javascript you're setting the content type to `application/json`. If the server is not set up to accept that type then you'll get a 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the trailing comma in `"user": "xyz",`. A trailing comma [is disallowed in json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201856/2441442) while perfect valid in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

I tested it using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) *(I can highly recommend, when working with APIs)*.

With a comma we get simple 400 - Bad request:

[image: With a comma]

Without a comma, we get at least an invalid token:

[image]