# json.loads() returns a string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-3.6

Why is json.loads() returning a string? Here's is my code:

```
import json

d = """{
    "reference": "123432",
    "business_date": "2019-06-18",
    "final_price": 40,
    "products": [
        {
            "quantity": 4,
            "original_price": 10,
            "final_price": 40,
        }
    ]
}"""

j = json.loads(json.dumps(d))
print(type(j))
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
```

Shouldn't it returning a json object? What change is required here?

Comment: remove the quotes in d before and after, `{` and `}` resp.

Comment: ```{
    "reference": "123432",
    "business_date": "2019-06-18",
    "final_price": 40,
    "products": [
        {
            "quantity": 4,
            "original_price": 10,
            "final_price": 40,
        }
    ]
}
```JSON Data
```Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 10 column 9 (char 215)
None

[Program finished]```Commenting for future readers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two points:

1. You have a typo in your `products` key : `"final_price": 40,` should be `"final_price": 40` (without comma)
2. `j` should be `json.loads(d)`

**Output**

> dict

**EDIT**

Reasons why you can not have a trailing comma in a json objects are explained in this post [Can you use a trailing comma in a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object)

> *Unfortunately the JSON specification does not allow a trailing comma. There are a few browsers that will allow it, but generally you need to worry about all browsers.*

Comment: the comma will not affect the result in python.

Comment: actually it does : `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 10 column 9 (char 215)`

Comment: `d = {'a':10,}` AND `d = {'a':10}` . Both will give the same result. Python is not case sensitive. Try it on your machine

Comment: and `json.loads('{"a":[10,]}')` vs  `json.loads('{"a":[10]}')` ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object

Comment: You are correct here. I never thought about it. I have learnt something new today.

Comment: It's a subset of a big json. I couldn't pin down that trailing comma. Removing it resolved it. Thanks!

Comment: How can I return a Json not dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

**ast.literal_eval:** Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, None, bytes and sets.
[more details](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast

d = """{
    "reference": "123432",
    "business_date": "2019-06-18",
    "final_price": 40,
    "products": [
        {
            "quantity": 4,
            "original_price": 10,
            "final_price": 40,
        }
    ]
}"""

data = ast.literal_eval(d)

print(data)
print(type(data))
```

O/P:

```
{'reference': '123432', 'business_date': '2019-06-18', 'final_price': 40, 'products': [{'quantity': 4, 'original_price': 10, 'final_price': 40}]}
<class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 3):

1). The type of `d` AND `j` will remain same.

```
import json

d = """{
 "reference": "123432",
 "business_date": "2019-06-18",
 "final_price": 40,
 "products": [
    {
        "quantity": 4,
        "original_price": 10,
        "final_price": 40,
    }
    ]
}"""
print(type(d))

j = json.loads(json.dumps(d))
print(type(j))
```

2). Now Both have Dictionary type:-

```
import json

d = {
 "reference": "123432",
 "business_date": "2019-06-18",
 "final_price": 40,
 "products": [
    {
        "quantity": 4,
        "original_price": 10,
        "final_price": 40,
    }
    ]
}
print(type(d))

j = json.loads(json.dumps(d))
print(type(j))
```

This is the reason we use `json` format. 
I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `d` is supposed to be a JSON string. If it were, you wouldn't therefore need to dump it before loading it.

When I remove the string quotes, meaning that the `json.dumps` call is working on a dict not a string everything seems to come out fine:

```
import json

d = {
    "reference": "123432",
    "business_date": "2019-06-18",
    "final_price": 40,
    "products": [
        {
            "quantity": 4,
            "original_price": 10,
            "final_price": 40,
        }
    ]
}

j = json.loads(json.dumps(d))
print(type(j))
```

prints out

```
<class 'dict'>
```

Note, however, that trying to apply `json.loads` to the existing string will produce an error because JSON is less forgiving than Python, and doesn't allow dangling commas at the end of lists and dicts (see the `"final_price"` element definition).

Comment: It is a json string. But since it was not working simply with json.loads(s), I tried to dump it before loading it and it worked. But the issue was the trailing comma after 40 in 'final_price'. Removing it fixed the issue. Thanks for input.

Comment: That was my point - with the additional comma, it was no longer valid JSON, so passing it to `json.loads` errored with `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 10 column 9 (char 215)`. Anyway, glad it's resolved.

Comment: You are right. It's not json string anymore although earlier it was. Actually its a subset of a big json string I got from json.dumps(json_obj). Editing it in notepad++ left that trailing comma.