# Unable to resolve module when using babel module resolver + eslint + index files in react application

Tags: visual-studio-code, babeljs, create-react-app

I am trying to use [babel module resolver plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver?activeTab=readme) with eslint + create react app but I am unable to start the application, getting the error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1237
throw err;
^

SyntaxError: C:\Users\enisr\Desktop\projects\pcPartPicker\jsconfig.json: 
Unexpected token } in JSON at position 166
at parse (<anonymous>)
```

I have set up a git repo showcasing the problem https://github.com/sgoulas/pcPartPicker

I have read the instructions [in the docs](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/blob/e4a1165816b8f98663417366e2642444e1997c73/DOCS.md) and in the [original repository](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/tree/e4a1165816b8f98663417366e2642444e1997c73) and I am unable to configure it correctly.

My configuration files are the following:

`.babelrc`

```
{
"plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
        "extensions": [
            ".js",
            ".jsx",
            ".es",
            ".es6",
            ".mjs"
        ],
            "root": ["./src"],
            "alias": {
                "@components": "./src/components"
            }
        }
    ]
]
}
```

`jsconfig.json`

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
         "*": ["src/*"],
        "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
    }
}
}
```

`webpack.config.dev.js`

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  include: path.appSrc,
  loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
  options: {
    plugins: [
     [
    "module-resolver",
    {
      root: ["./src/App"],
      alias: {
        "@components": "./src/components",
      },
        },
      ],
    ],
    cacheDirectory: true,
  },
};
```

My component:

```
import { GPUtable, CPUtable } from "@components/Tables";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <GPUtable />
      <CPUtable />
    </>
  );
};
```

export default App;

Comment: @JBallin I don't think so, since this React project has no typescript in it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to eject your create-react-app for this? I don't think you just add a webpack config on top of CRA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some minor fixes you need to make (below), but the main issue is that Create React App does not expose the webpack config, you'll need to [eject](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) to edit that.

1. `npm run eject`
2. Merge the `babel` configs: delete the `babel` key + value at the bottom of the package.json, and paste the value into your bablrc (`"presets": ["react-app"],`).
3. Add `import React from 'react';` to the top of `App.js`

Confirmed locally that the app will run.

---

Other suggested fixes

1. Your jsconfig has a trailing comma after the array value in `@components/*`. You need to remove it because JSON doesn’t [support them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201856/4722345).
2. You need to fix the `include` path in weback.config.dev.js. `appSrc` isn't something defined on the node `path` module. Try using `path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')` - the example in their docs is creating/importing a `paths` object with `appSrc` pointing to this value.
3. You're missing `test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,` in webpack.config.dev.js.

Comment: Removing the trailing comma does not solve the issue. I still get "Can't resolve '@components/Tables" error compilation error.

Comment: I implemented the changes and now I get "Module not found: Can't resolve '@components/Tables' in 'C:\Users\enisr\Desktop\projects\pcPartPicker\src'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'". In any case I am pushing all the changes I am doing to the repo.

Comment: I am still getting './src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@components/Tables' in 'C:\Users\enisr\Desktop\projects\pcPartPicker\src'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'; in my compilation terminal. Updated the repo with the change you mentioned.

Comment: Alright I got it working now, finally had a chance to pull it down.

Comment: the issue was resolved after following your instructions. Thank you for your help and for sticking with me so far. Have a nice day.

Comment: Awesome, you too! Thank you for the bounty ❤️