# how to solve or find problems in VS Code Editor settings.json file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My settings.json file shows 3 problems with my settings but I can't find it. My settings is below -

```
{
    "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Community Material Theme Ocean",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "javascript.validate.enable": false,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "files.associations": {
        "*.js": "javascriptreact"
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "liveServer.settings.https": {
        "enable": true
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
}
```

Comment: What problems are you seeing?

Comment: There's an extra `,` on the last closing curly brace

Comment: @Alejandro not showing exact problems. just became yellow and when I hovered over the settings tab it was saying ` 3 problems in the file`

Comment: You can use the [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) extension for VSCode to auto-validate your JavaScript/JSON files.

Comment: won't it misbehave with flowtype ? i had to use "javascript.validate.enable": false, for flowtype @sbolel

Comment: if there is a problem the tooltip will give a hint of what to fix

Comment: Copy paste into an online json linter - you usually get better indications of the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I just removed this part

```
"liveServer.settings.https": {
        "enable": true
    },
```

and now no problem is showing. but don't know why

Comment: That's correct. It's because the last property in a JSON list shouldn't have a comma after the closing brace. JSON doesn't support trailing commas - see [this answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object#:~:text=Unfortunately%20the%20JSON%20specification%20does%20not%20allow%20a,end%20up%20with%20code%20that%20looks%20like%20this%3A)

Comment: but it is not the last property and after taking it out I've no problem even though my last property has comma @sbolel

Comment: hmm. The extra comma that I was referring to is after the closing brace of `"[html]": { ... },`

Comment: @sbolel it is still there but now there is no problem