# Creating a "Discovery rules" in Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

Good afternoon. I can't creating a "Discovery rules" in Zabbix. Items not created.

I'm creating a "Discovery rules" in Zabbix for server hard drives. Next, I will watch their smart. I use "smartmontools".
Created a "Discovery rules":

```
Type: Zabbix agent
Key: system.run["smartctl --scan-open"]
```

I get:

```
/dev/sda -d ata # /dev/sda, ATA device
/dev/sdb -d sat # /dev/sdb [SAT], ATA device
/dev/sdc -d sat # /dev/sdc [SAT], ATA device
```

I convert the result to the form (through preprocessing in JavaScript):

```
[{"data":[{"{#DISK}":"sda"},{"{#DISK}":"sdb"},]}]
```

Next, I create a "Item prototypes":

```
Name: DISK {#DISK}
Type: Zabbix agent
Key: system.run["smartctl -A /dev/{$DISK}"]
```

But for some reason, the "Item prototypes" does not appear on the server.
Help me please. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
It should have been done like this:

```
   {"data":[{"{#DISK}":"sda"},{"{#DISK}":"sdb"}]}       // Right
   [{"data":[{"{#DISK}":"sda"},{"{#DISK}":"sdb"},]}]    // wrong
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
const sd = value.match(/sd(.)/g);
const col = sd.length;
const arr = [];
const mcleftbegin = '{"{#DISK}":"';
const mcleft = ',{"{#DISK}":"';
const mcright = '"}';
for (i = 0; i <= col; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        if (i == 0) {
            arr.push(mcleftbegin + sd[i] + mcright); 
        }
        else {
            arr.push(mcleft + sd[i] + mcright);
        }
    }
}
arr.pop();
var jsonl = '{"data":[';
var jsonr = ']}';
const coll = (col / 2) - 1;
for (y = 0; y <= coll; y++) {
    if (y == coll) {
        jsonl = jsonl + arr[y] + jsonr;
    }
    else {
        jsonl = jsonl + arr[y];
    }
}
return jsonl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid, that's probably why it doesn't work. See [Can you use a trailing comma in a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201782/can-you-use-a-trailing-comma-in-a-json-object)

Also: `system.run` is deprecated, do not use it unless for tests.

Check the "info" column in the LLD page for error messages. You should see something like:

> cannot parse as a valid JSON object: invalid JSON object value starting character at: ']}]'

**Update** on the code in the selfanswer: you can use `JSON.stringify()` and simplify a lot:

```
const sd = value.match(/sd(.)/g);
var data = [];
for (i = 0; i <= sd.length; i++) {
    data.push({"{#DISK}": sd[i]}); 
}
return JSON.stringify(data);
```